# Touch Event not working properly..libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to execute a function only when the actor on my stage is touched..
But the problem is the function gets executed irrespective of where its touched on the stage..
Even if its touched in some random place on stage the function is executed..
I want the function to execute only when the actor is touched..I have setbounds...Still its not working..

```
public Restart() 
    {
       atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("pages-info.atlas"));
       sprite = atlas.createSprite("restart");
       this.touchable = true;
        sprite.setBounds(x, y, sprite.getWidth(), sprite.getHeight());

    }



public void draw(SpriteBatch batch,float parentAlpha)
    {       
        batch.draw(sprite, x, y , width, height  );

    }



@Override
    public Actor hit(float x, float y) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Gdx.app.log( FirstGame.LOG, " restart working " );
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Your code does not match the question you are asking. If you want to get callbacks when an actor is touched, then you only need to add a listener to that actor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hit` method is not doing what you think it does.  The `hit` method is for *testing* if the current actor intersects the given x,y or not, so its always called.  (Its useful if you want to throw away "hits" because your actor is not rectangular.)

Use [`addListener`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#addListener%28com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.EventListener%29) to add an event listener to receive touch events and react to them.

Comment: I tried inputlistener...I think its taken out in the version i'm using.. :(
I just need to trigger a function when my actor is touched..Which is the simplest way to do it ?

Comment: Read this: https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2d#Event_system.  `InputListener` has always existed, so there may be some other problem.

Comment: I used buttons and clicklistener...
Got what i was looking for..Thanks a lot P.T for ur replies..
Much appreciated..